# Specifying custom error bars in ggplot2 when using facet_grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created multiple bar charts from my data, using `stat_summary`. However, I want to manually specify the limits of the error bars (instead of using `mean_cl_boot`). How can this be done for data graphed using `facet_grid`?

The code I used to create the charts is below:

```
graph <- ggplot(slantclean, aes(x = View,value, fill = Texture))

graph + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge") + 
     stat_summary(fun.data = mean_cl_boot, geom = "pointrange", 
                     position = position_dodge(width = 0.90)) + 
     labs(x = "View", y = "Vertical height of ellipse (cm)", fill = "Texture") + 
     facet_grid( Shape ~ TNOGroup)
```

Unfortunately, the complex nature of the data means that a minimal example is impossible. The data frame can be accessed [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs5sq1yjomiaqe3/data.Rda). An example of the plot is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88NA8.png).

Comment: You likely will be more successful if you summarize your data outside the ggplot call (not relying on `stat_summary`). Then you could specify the size of the error bars at that time and just use that summarized data as a data argument to `geom_pointrange`.

Comment: I ended up doing this, was surprisingly simple. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one write a function to create custom error bars for use with ggplot2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6717675/how-can-one-write-a-function-to-create-custom-error-bars-for-use-with-ggplot2)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define your own function to use in `stat_summary()`. If you use `geom="pointrange"` in `stat_summary()` then your function should give `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` value in one dataframe.

Here is just example to make function `my.fun` that calculates minimal, maximal and mean value. When used in `stat_summary()` this values will be calculated for each level in your data.

```
my.fun<-function(x){data.frame(ymin=min(x),ymax=max(x),y=mean(x))}

graph <- ggplot(slantclean, aes(x = View,value, fill = Texture))

graph + stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", position = "dodge") + 
  stat_summary(fun.data = my.fun, geom = "pointrange", position = position_dodge(width = 0.90)) + 
  labs(x = "View", y = "Vertical height of ellipse (cm)", fill = "Texture") + 
  facet_grid( Shape ~ TNOGroup)
```

[image]

Comment: congrats on reaching 10K @Didzis!

Comment: I had to do as the comment on my original post suggested, as R was calculating the means across groups oddly. However, this is very useful for the future, thankyoU!