# How to add mean and S.D on boxplot of ggplot2 or change the default whiskers definition to represent one S.D. above and below the mean of the data?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have following boxplot. Three grids are are for three different sites. Three colors denote three different methods. I want to add mean and mean+/-S.D on each boxplot. A custom boxplot where the whiskers represent one standard deviation above and below the mean of the data is also a solution. I have tried two options that I found in internet but none helped.

[image: Three grids are are for three different sites. Three color denotes three methods. I want to add mean and mean+/-S.D on each boxplot.]

Sample R code:

```
library(stats)  
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(50)
df <- data.frame(
site = rep(c("A", "B","C"),20),
# method=sample(c("method1", "method2","method3"), 60, replace = TRUE),
control = as.factor(c(rep(0,30),rep(1,30))),
x=1:60,
method1=rnorm(60),
method2=rnorm(60)+0.1,
method3=rnorm(60)+0.2

)  

m=melt(df,id.vars=c("control","site","x"))

p=ggplot(data=m, aes(control,y=value)) + 
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=variable))+ 
facet_grid(~site) 
print(p)
```

I have tried two options:

Option 1.

```
sd_upper=function(x) { mean(x)+sd(x) }
sd_lower=function(x) { mean(x)-sd(x) }

p=p+
stat_summary(fun.y=sd_upper, colour="yellow",geom="point", shape=95, size=5,show_guide = FALSE)+
stat_summary(fun.y=sd_lower, colour="yellow",geom="point", shape=95, size=5,show_guide = FALSE)+
stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="yellow",geom="point", shape=95, size=5,show_guide = FALSE)
```

[image]

The three points are plotted only on the middle boxplot.

Option 2.

```
 min.mean.sd.max <- function(x) {
 r <- c(min(x), mean(x) - sd(x), mean(x), mean(x) + sd(x), max(x))
 names(r) <- c("ymin", "lower", "middle", "upper", "ymax")
 r
 }

p=p+
stat_summary(fun.data = min.mean.sd.max,aes(fill=variable), geom = "boxplot")
```

[image]

This is not what I want!

Is there any way to change the default definition of geom_boxplot in ggplot2 so that it plots mean and S>D?

Comment: your title is misleading. You just want to add three points to each corresponding boxplot?

Comment: that would be one solution.

Comment: To get your summary stats lined up, you'd need to `dodge` (as in `position = position_dodge(width = .75)` ).  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16154191/2461552).